# Xcode c++ function list

Tags: xcode

I want to see a list of all the functions defined in the current file in Xcode, just like the taglist plugin in VIM. I am not familiar with Xcode. Is it possible to do that in Xcode? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can view that information in the "Jump Bar" at the top of the window.

Whenever you have a file open, you should see a thin bar above the file editor/viewer that has the name of your project along with a path to the file you have open. When you are in a .m or .h file, the last item in that bar will be the current method that your cursor is in if it is in one.

If you click on that, it will give you a list of all methods in that file, and clicking on one of those will scroll the window to it.

Here is an example from an old project of mine:

This is the jump bar that has a path to your file and allows you to select other files:

[image: topBar]

This is the list of methods in your current file if you click on the current method:

[image: method list]

Comment: Thanks, it's really difficult to find :)